# Tensorflow MNIST dataloader giving interlinked numpy array

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I am reading a batch of MNIST data using the inbuilt Tensorflow datasets module. That gives a numpy array as a batch. However, if I copy the array into another variables and make changes to that second variables, the original batch array is also changed.
I am doubtful as to why there is any connection between the original array and the copied array.

You can test on this CoLab link:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DN4n5_YCO33LozxtidM7STqEAUWypNOv

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import numpy as np
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

def test_reconstruction(mnist, h=28, w=28, batch_size=100):
    # Test the trained model: reconstruction
    batch = mnist.test.next_batch(batch_size)
    batch_clean = batch[0]

    print('before damage:', np.mean(batch_clean))
    batch_damaged = np.reshape(batch_clean, (batch_size, 28, 28))
    tmp = batch_damaged
    tmp[:, 10:20, 10:20] = 0
    print('after damage:', np.mean(batch_clean))

test_reconstruction(mnist)
```

Expected: Both the print statements should return the same mean value

Actual: I am getting different mean values for the two print statements

Answer (score 0):

In your line `batch_damaged = np.reshape(batch_clean, (batch_size, 28, 28))` you copy the reference of batch_clean and not its values. You should use `numpy.copy` to return a copy of your array.
`batch_damaged = np.copy(np.reshape(batch_clean, (batch_size, 28, 28)))`

Comment: Thanks for this insight. This indeed solved the issue. Can you please explain as to why the reference of parent array was copied. I mean for usual numpy arrays we never face this kind of an attachment to parent issue?

Comment: This is due to numpy reshape function that returns a new view object if possible. Have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html